Designing an SDE satisfied by $\frac{B(t)}{1+t}$
Let $B$ be the Brownian motion. I want to find a stochastic differential equation satisfied by the process $$X(t) = \frac{B(t)}{1+t}.$$ I am trying to use Itô's lemma for $f(x,t) = \frac{x}{1+t}$ but got stuck with the second derivatives (can't get rid of them). Any idea how to overcome that?

The Brownian motion $dX=Adt+DdW$ transforms for $F=f(X,t)$ as
$$dF=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(X,t)dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(X,t)dX+\tfrac{1}{2}D^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(X,t)dt.$$
Substitution of $f(x,t)=x/(1+t)$ then gives for $F=X/(1+t)$ the differential equation
$$dF=-\frac{F}{1+t}dt+\frac{1}{1+t}(Adt+DdW),$$
the second derivative term vanishes because $f$ is linear in $x$.
